# How to replace value of first array by value from another array?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays with the following structure:

First one: `['banana', 'apple', 'orange']`

Second: `[{name: 'banana', price: 1}, {name: 'apple', price: 3}, {name: 'orange', price: 4}]`

So I want to replace value in first array by price, as a result I want to get

[1, 3, 4]

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` the second array, and return the `price` of it.

```js
let arr1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']

let arr2 = [{name: 'banana', price: 1}, {name: 'apple', price: 3}, {name: 'orange', price: 4}]

let arr3 = arr2.map(elem=>{
  if(arr1.indexOf(elem.name) !== -1){
    return elem.price
  }
})

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: yes. Worked really well. indexOf really helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const products = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
const data = [{name: 'banana', price: 1}, {name: 'apple', price: 3}, {name: 'orange', price: 4}]

const prices = products.map(product => {
  return data.find(data => data.name === product).price
})
console.log(products, prices)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'];
const arr2 = [{name: 'banana', price: 1}, {name: 'apple', price: 3}, {name: 'orange', price: 4}];

console.log(arr1.map(fruit => arr2.find(({ name }) => fruit === name).price));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use map to store the `{name->price}` by iterating in second array and iterate through the name in first array to return the price array. We could have used two nested loops to get price array, however using map is faster than using two nested loops.

```js
const first = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
const second = [{name: 'banana', price: 1}, {name: 'apple', price: 3}, {name: 'orange', price: 4}];
const map = new Map();
second.forEach((item)=>{
  map.set(item.name,item.price);
})

const result = first.map((name)=>map.get(name));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data gets large, you should probably avoid scanning the whole array of objects over and over again. You can use a `Map` object to key your data by name -- using its constructor. Then the lookup will run smooth:

```js
let keys = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'];
let data = [{name: 'banana', price: 1}, {name: 'apple', price: 3}, {name: 'orange', price: 4}];

let map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.name, o]));
let result = keys.map(key => map.get(key).price);

console.log(result);
```

If your data objects have other properties, you can similarly reach them with `map.get(key).otherproperty`... Or just the complete object with `map.get(key)`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, for example. Should be self-explanatory.

```js
var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
const fruitDataSet = [
 {name: 'banana', price: 1},
 {name: 'apple', price: 3},
 {name: 'orange', price: 4},
 {name: 'ImNotAFruit', price: 4}
]

for(const fruitData of fruitDataSet){
 let index = fruits.findIndex(x => x == fruitData.name)
   if(index != -1){
    fruits.splice(index, 1, fruitData.price)
   }
}

console.log(fruits)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is a oneliner**

```js
let array = [
  {name: 'banana', price: 1}, 
  {name: 'apple', price: 3}, 
  {name: 'orange', price: 4}
 ]

let result = array.reduce((acc,item) => acc.concat(item.price) , [])
alert (result)
```